# why is jetpack compose function called when its input parameters change?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I mean where it shows why it is called because of parameter change **in the source code.**
Thanks!

Comment: Can your be more clear about what you are asking. Are you asking why function are called when their parameters change? How compose determines when to call a function when its parameters change? How determine why a function is being called  when the call was unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

This is done by the Compose Compiler plug-in.

The source code is [here](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/general/compiler_plugin/).